# Check is a message was 'seen' yet?

Tags: mailkit

What's the optimal way to check if a particular MimeMessage was 'seen' yet. Meaning: how to check if the '\Seen' flag is set for a particular MimeMessage/UnqiueId?

I found the methods to set/change that flag, but now how to check if the flag is set yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to use the `Fetch` (or `FetchAsync`) methods.

Fetch is how you obtain any and all information about a message.

```
var results = folder.Fetch (new UniqueId[] { uid }, MessageSummaryItems.Flags);
var seen = results.FirstOrDefault ()?.Flags.Value.HasFlag (MessageFlags.Seen);
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification

I was hoping to have that info at hand on the MimeMessage which I already pulled from the IMAP server (to avoid the additional query)

Similar fashion I was looking to pull that info right from the .MessageFlagsChanged event (again, to avoid the additional query)